# How to change link sizes individually while hovering?

Tags: html, css

I want my links to zoom out a bit whenever I hover over it, However I have no idea how I can separate the links to do hover individually.

```css
body{
  background: gray;
}

.link a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.41);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class='link' style="text-align:center" style="text-decoration:none">

  <a id='left' href="how.html">How to Avoid Fighting</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='center' href="why.html">Why You Should Not Fight</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='right' href="Ways.html">Ways to Fight</a>
</div>
```

This is what I have but I can't figure out how to stop the links from hovering together.

Comment: Have you tried using the child selector? `.link > a`

Comment: Your existing `.link a:hover` rule should already only affect the element being hovered, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: I hope you'll explain us (and yourself) why did you decide to set the color as white (over a white background) when the mouse is not hovering. Just to unnecessarily complicate a very super easy scenario I guess.

Comment: the background is actually grey, I just didn't add it into the example.

Comment: it could be also red as far as I know... but if you omit such an important factor you are making life harder to people attempting to suggest a solution. As soon as you run the code nothing gets shown and at first sight you can't even tell where to hover

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm just in a rush since I finish this soon. The problem I have is that the links won't zoom out in transition. I can change the font size on hover, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want it to growing bigger when hovering but it either doesn't work, or the link transition out together.

Comment: You may like to look into CSS scale property.

Comment: I've tried using it transform:scale(); but it does not affect anything.

Comment: Could you put that code into a snippet in your question because something like transform: scale(2) should beOK.

Comment: the culprit was trying to scale an inline element that cannot have a size but it's just controlled by its content

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to scale the elements when on hover, you could use `transform: scale(1.2);` so that the link will get bigger.

It's important to note that the browser default for the `display` css property of an `<a>` element is `display: inline` and as such it wouldn't have a size at all and the scaling wouldn't work.

So to make it work you need to change it as `display: inline-block`

```css
body{
  background: gray;
}

.link a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.41);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  
  /*so that the element has an actual size (to scale)*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*it will just smoothen the transition over time when it kicks in*/
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.link a:hover {
  color: #000000;

  /*scale the element size a factor x1.2*/
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class='link'>
  <a id='left' href="how.html">How to Avoid Fighting</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='center' href="why.html">Why You Should Not Fight</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a id='right' href="Ways.html">Ways to Fight</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you want to do, if you want to change the font size on mouse hover you can do it in your .link a:hover rule

```css
.link a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color:#000fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.41);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  
}

.link a:hover{
  color: #000000;
  font-size:20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='link' style="text-align:center"  style="text-decoration:none" >     

      <a id='left' href="how.html">How to Avoid Fighting</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
      
      <a id='center' href="why.html">Why You Should Not Fight</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     

      <a id='right' href="Ways.html">Ways to Fight</a>
    </div>
```